# How can I have a screen saver in Ubuntu?

Tags: 15.04, screensaver

How can I have a screen saver in Ubuntu? Is there something I need to install to get it back?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl-extra
```

will install `xscreensaver` and a few cool packages.

If I remember well, using:

```
xscreensaver-demo
```

Will activate the daemon, then your screen will lock typing:

```
xscreensaver
```

or pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SUPPR</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness: Ubuntu has removed `gnome-screensaver` in the past, because it was a complete mess of a software. They (Canonical) decided, that they will make their own fork of `xscreensaver`, which also became a complete mess, and also a security issue (it was also the lockscreen, which did not work very well).

So, Ubuntu has dropped the support for screensavers by default. You can install `xscreensaver` manually, as @Kotshi said. However, you should know, that it is not very secure either, I definitely would not install a `setuid root` program to have a "nice" screensaver.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing beats `xset dpms force off`.
`xscrensaver` is the worst screensaver, it's old, it's ugly and above all it's not saving anything with its Windows-like energy wasting animations!